# Python: Int not iterable error

Tags: python

I'm attempting to get my feet wet with python on Project Euler, but I'm having an issue with the first problem (find the sum of the multiples of 3 or 5 up to 1,000). I can successfully print out multiples of three and five, but when I attempt to include the sum function I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Any help would be appreciated.

```
n = 100
p = 0
while p<n:
   p = p + 1
x = range(0, p)

# check to see if numbers are divisable by 3 or 5
def numcheck(x): 
   for numbers in x:
      if numbers%3==0 and numbers%5==0:
          sum(numbers)
numcheck(x)
```

Comment: I just ran the code you posted and did not get that error. I see that you edited your code to remove the line that caused the error. What's your question now?

Comment: Woops, didn't realized I edited that out, one sec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the for-loop

```
for numbers in x:
```

"numbers" steps through the elements in x one at a time, for each pass through the loop.
It would be perhaps better to name the variable "number" because you are only getting
one number at a time. "numbers" equals an integer each time through the loop.

```
sum(numbers)
```

throws a TypeError because the function sum() expects an iterable object (like a list of numbers), not just one integer.

So perhaps try:

```
def numcheck(x):
    s=0
    for number in x:
        if number%3==0 and number%5==0:
            s+=number
    print(s)
numcheck(range(1000))
```

Comment: Changed accepted answer to yours for providing an explanation as well, thanks (here's hoping I can get the next problem on my own).

Comment: +1 for suggesting that variable names match what they actually are.  It's amazing how many bugs can be prevented just by having clear names.

Answer (score 5):

numbers needs to be a list or similar when it is passed to sum(). In the code example above, it is an integer - one of the integers from x.

Try something like:

```
numbers = [num for num in x if num%3==0 and num%5 ==0]
print sum(numbers)
```

Comment: `sum` takes a iterable so this works too: `sum(n for n in x if n%3==0 and n%5==0)`

Comment: That's by far the most Pythonic solution, and a one-liner.  


Recasting imperative code into comprehensions is a whole worthy subject in itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `sum` function expects a list, not a single number.

When you do `for numbers in`, then the variable `numbers` has a single integer object.  Add a `print` statement, you'll see that `numbers` is a single number.

You might want to accumulate all the multiples of 3 and 5 in a list.  Once you have the list, you can then use the `sum` function on that list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like what follows.

```
def numcheck(x):
    total = 0
    for number in x:
        if number % 3 == 0 or and number % 5 == 0:
            total += number
    print total
```

Alternatively, you could append each of the divisible numbers to a list, and then call sum() on that list.

Comment: Shame on you for providing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

help(sum)
Help on built-in function sum in module **builtin**:

sum(...)
    sum(sequence[, start]) -> value

```
Returns the sum of a sequence of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the sequence is
empty, returns start.
```

(END)

You are passing numbers which is of type int to sum(), but sum takes a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this:

```
n = 100

# the next 4 lines are just to confirm that xrange is n numbers starting at 0
junk = xrange(n)
print junk[0]  # print first number in sequence
print junk[-1] # print last number in sequence
print "================"

# check to see if numbers are divisable by 3 or 5
def numcheck(x): 
   for numbers in x:
      if numbers%3==0 and numbers%5==0:
          print numbers

numcheck(xrange(n))
```

You may find it strange that I pass xrange(n) as a parameter. This is an iterator that
will eventually produce the list of n numbers as you go through the loop in numcheck. It's a bit like passing a pointer to a function in C. The key thing is that by using xrange, you do not need to allocate any memory for the list of numbers, so you can more easily run a check on the first billion integers, for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I entirely understand xrange yet (I'm not all too familiar with pointers as well), so bare with me.

So while range generates a list of, let's say 100 numbers, on the spot, xrange would generate a single number, check if that number matches whatever conditions you've given it, and continue moving on to the next number until it reaches 100?

Comment: `xrange()` was invented because sometimes we call `range()` and we don't actually want the whole list.  A `for` loop in Python always sets its variable to elements from a list (or something other than a list that is "iterable").  Suppose you want to do something a million times.  With `for x in range(1000000):` you build a list of a million integer objects, and then you use it once and discard it.  `xrange()` instead of returning a list, returns an iterator, and the `for` loop knows how to ask the iterator for one value at a time.  No need to build and destroy a huge list.

Comment: `xrange()` worked out very well, and in Python 3.x, there is no longer a `range()` that returns a full list; `range()` in Python 3.x acts like `xrange()` in Python 2.x.  In Python 3.x if you actually want the list, you simply do this:  `list(range(1000))`  The `list` type takes the iterator and turns it into a full list.  In fact, all the method functions in Python that used to return full lists return iterators in Python 3.x.  You can force them to expand to a full list if you want, and when you don't care, the iterator is more efficient.